# Installation of gnome-core on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: 14.04, gnome, dependencies

I'm using [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS (Trusty Tahr) server:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I'm trying to install a minimal Ubuntu OS, but when I enter the command

```
apt-get install gnome-core
```

I get this output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-core : Depends: eog (>= 3.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After using `apt-cache policy gnome-core eog`, the output was:

```
gnome-core:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 1:3.8+4ubuntu3
Version table:
     1:3.8+4ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages eog:   Installed: (none)   Candidate: 3.10.2-0ubuntu5   Version table:
     3.10.2-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

After forcing *eog* installation using `apt-get install eog`, the output was:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
eog :
Depends: libpeas-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gir1.2-peas-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After that, using command `apt-cache policy libpeas-1.0-0 gir1.2-peas-1.0`:

The output was:

> libpeas-1.0-0:   Installed: (none)   Candidate: 1.8.1-2ubuntu2
>    Version table:
>        1.8.1-2ubuntu2 0
>           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages gir1.2-peas-1.0:   Installed: (none)   Candidate:
>    1.8.1-2ubuntu2   Version table:
>         1.8.1-2ubuntu2 0
>           500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

Then using command `apt-get install libpeas-1.0-0 gir1.2-peas-1.0`, the output was:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libpeas-1.0-0 : Depends: libpython3.4 (>= 3.4~b1) but it is not going to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

After using command `apt-cache policy libpython3.4` the output was:

> libpython3.4:
>
> Installed: (none)
>
> Candidate: 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1
>
> Version table:

```
> 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 0
```

> ```
> 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
>     500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
>  3.4.0-2ubuntu1 0
>     500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
> ```

After using command `apt-get install libpython3.4` the output Was:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> libpython3.4 : Depends: libpython3.4-stdlib (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1) but >3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

After using command `sudo apt-get install libpython3.4-stdlib` the output was:

> Reading package lists... Done
>     Building dependency tree
>     Reading state information... Done
>     libpython3.4-stdlib is already the newest version.
>     0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the correct version of `libpython3.4-stdlib`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpython3.4-stdlib=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 libpython3.4-minimal=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1
```

because `libpython3.4-stdlib` needs **exact** version `3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1` and **not** your installed version `3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1`.

After that install `gnome-core` via

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core
```

and install some uninstalled packages again

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-release python3 update-notifier-common
```

And at the end

```
sudo apt-mark auto libpython3.4-stdlib libpython3.4-minimal
```